# How to copy file to a new location having path length more than 260 characters in vista?

Tags: vb.net

in my previous question as follows:

"**How to create a copy of a file having length more than 260 characters**."

I have asked almost same qustion and I got a solution to rename the directory name and then copy to a new location. But as per the client's requirement we can't rename the directory in any case.

So now my problem is when we try to copy a file having path length (including file name) more than **260 characters**, (say 267 characters), it allows us to copy manually but throws an exception programmetically in vista OS.

Please let me know if any one has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is just with the length of the file (not the preceding path), then you can use the short name version of the file (probabaly Outloo~1.xls ).

However, the only real viable solution is to use network redirection or SUBST command to shorten the path.  I can imagine that you'd have to be keeping track of the path length in your program, and spawn a SUBST drive letter when the length is exceeded... dropping the drive letter when it's no longer needed.  Ugly programming, but no hope.

Or

I know some unicode version of windows api functions (copyfileex..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852(VS.85).aspx) can handle to 32,767 chars.

Try to name it with a \\?\ prefix, for example, \\?\D:\. I'm not sure if CLR uses this kind of naming style, but you can give it a try.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have written the API function CopyFile passing file path with pre-pending "\\?\" but I am not getting any output even though it is not showing any error. Please suggest...

Comment: Please check your file naming convention via  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx
Also check for copyfileEx.
It may help.

Answer (score 3):

Prepend **`\\?\`** to your path to enable path lengths up to 32767 characters long.  E.g:

```
copy \\?\C:\big\dir\hierarchy\myfile.txt \\?\C:\tohere.txt
```

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) has more details.

I've only tested this with `DIR` in WinXP, but that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if [compression tools like 7zip](http://dotnetperls.com/Content/7-%5Aip-Examples.aspx) are limited by the length of the path in Vista.

If not, that means a "copy by program" would by:

- compressed the tree of directories/file you want to copy
- copy the .zip/.rar to the destination
- uncompress